# How to disable transaction rollback a method in transaction rollback enable class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have two methods named saveNewCustormerDetails and storeFailCustomerSaveDetails. If any exception jump inside saveNewCustormerDetails method then transaction will be the rollback, when an exception occurs, I need to store the message of exception in the database with customer mobile number. To do it, I use the storeFailCustomerSaveDetails method. but It does not work because also rollback store fails customers saving details. So, I need to disable the rollback process only for the storeFailCustomerSaveDetails method. does there any way to do it?

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustormerService {

        private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
        private final CustomerSaveFailsRepository customerSaveFailsRepository;


    @Autowired
    public CustomerServiceImpl(CustomerRepository customerRepository, CustomerSaveFailsRepository customerSaveFailsRepository){
            this.customerRepository = customerRepository; 
            this.customerSaveFailsRepository = customerSaveFailsRepository;
    } 

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
        @Override
        public void saveNewCustormerDetails(CustomerDTO customerDTO) {
        try{

            CustomerEntity customerEntity = new CustomerEntity();
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(customerDTO, customerEntity);  
            customerRepository.save(customerEntity);

        }catch(Exception e){

            LOGGER.error("Method saveNewCustormerDetails : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            storeFailCustomerSaveDetails(customerDTO, e);
                        throw e;    

        }
    }

    private void storeFailCustomerSaveDetails(CustomerDTO customerDTO, Exception ex){
        try{
                CustomerSaveFailsEntity customerSaveFailsEntity = new CustomerSaveFailsEntity(customerDTO.getContact(), e.getMessage()); 
                customerSaveFailsRepository.save(customerSaveFailsEntity);

            }catch(Exception e){

            LOGGER.error("Method storeFailCustomerSaveDetails : " + e.getMessage() ,e);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NEVER) above you method

Comment: Move to a different class, annotate with `@Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)` and it will run in a new transaction.

Comment: to complete comment @M.Deinum, you can use also `@Transactional(NOT_SUPPORTED)`, https://blog.fireheart.in/a?ID=00300-f77c2d0d-2695-489f-bfda-ae6c2ce002d1